# Expectation of product of steps in a branching process.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I just found an interesting problem from 2013 on Duke's website:
Show that for a branching process ($Z_n$) with expected offspring μ, one has: $$E[Z_nZ_m]=\mu^{n-m}E[Z_m^2] $$ for $0 \leq m \leq n$.
Any ideas?  I can't tell if calculating the covariance first would be useful.  Perhaps, we use conditional probabilities.  I'm not sure how this would play out.

Found at:
http://sites.duke.edu/probabilityworkbook/covariance-of-a-branching-process/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an application of the tower property for conditional expectations. We first show 
$$\boldsymbol{E}[ Z_n | Z_m] = \mu^{n-m} Z_m,$$
which will be the crucial step in obtaining the formula.

In the case $n =m+1$, since the expected number of offspring is $\mu$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{E}[ Z_{m+1} |Z_m] = \mu\, Z_m,
\end{align*}
We proceed by induction and suppose $\boldsymbol{E}[ Z_n | Z_m] = \mu^{n-m} Z_m$, and consider the case for $n+1$. By the tower property
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{E}[ Z_{n+1} | Z_m] & = \boldsymbol{E} \Big[ \boldsymbol{E}[ Z_{n+1}| Z_{n}]\, \Big|\,Z_m \Big]\\
& = \boldsymbol{E}[ \mu Z_{n} | Z_m ]\\
& = \mu \boldsymbol{E}[  Z_{n} | Z_m ] \\
& = \mu^{n-m+1}Z_m,
\end{align*}
which completes the induction. Now turning to your question, we note
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{E}[ Z_n Z_m] & = \boldsymbol{E} \Big [  \boldsymbol{E}[ Z_n | Z_m] Z_m \Big ] \\
& =\boldsymbol{E}[ \mu^{n-m} Z_m Z_m ]\\
& = \mu^{n-m} \boldsymbol{E}[ Z_m^2 ]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Owen. I don't see how you went from $E[Z_n|Z_m]=\mu^{n-m}Z_m$ to $E[E[Z_n|Z_m]]=E[\mu^{n-m}Z_n Z_n]$.  Those two lines seem incompatible to me.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What I get from those lines is $E[E[Z_n|Z_m]]=E[\mu^{n-m}Z_m]=\mu^{n-m}E[Z_m]=\mu^n$.  Also, why does $E[Z_n Z_m]=E[E[Z_n|Z_m]]$?

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in this line: it should read $E[Z_nZ_m] = E[ E[Z_n|Z_m] Z_m ] = \mu^{n-m} E[ Z_m^2]$. This has now been corrected.

Comment: Ok thanks, and why does $E[Z_n Z_m]=E[E[Z_n|Z_m]Z_m]$?

Comment: This is a property of conditional expectations: $E[Z_n Z_m] = E[ E[Z_n Z_m |Z_m] ] = E[ E[Z_n|Z_m] Z_m ]$, see for instance the wikipedia list of properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties.

Comment: By the way, if you are happy with this answer can you please consider accepting it!

Comment: Thanks.  And done!  I didn't know how to do that, sorry.

Comment: No problem... hope its all clear now.

Comment: How did you even get the first property?  i.e. $\boldsymbol{E}[ Z_{m+1} |Z_m] = \mu\, Z_m,$?

Comment: @Hunle, if there are $Z_n$ individuals in the population, and each is expected to have $\mu$ offspring, then you'd expect the next generation to have $\mu Z_n$ individuals, i.e. $ \mathbf E[ Z_{n+1} ] = \mu  \mathbf E [Z_n]$. As a less abstract example, if there's one individual in the first generation ($Z_0 = 1$), and they're expected to have $\mu$ off spring, then that's exactly to say that $\mathbf E[Z_1] = \mu$.

Comment: Yes but how does the conditional expectation come into play?  I understand $\mathbb{E}[Z_{m+1}]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{m}]*\mu$.  But you have written above $\mathbb{E}[Z_{m+1}| Z_{m}]= Z_{m+1}*\mu$.  You have conditioned on the left hand side, and somehow that removes the expected value on the RHS.  I do not understand how you were able to remove the expected value when you condition on $Z_m$.  Why can you do that here?         Is it using iterated conditioning (tower rule)? or partial averaging?  or neither one?

Comment: Now that I work this out...it seems like you can use mathematical induction to show $\mathbb{E}[Z_{m+1}| Z_{m}]= Z_{m+1}*\mu$ from $E[Z_1]=\mu$  as the base case.  Is that true?  If so, then perhaps it should be made explicit in the answer...

Comment: You can argue by induction, this would be similar to the part of the proof after the line you are currently inspecting: it would require the tower rule etc. The logic I put in my previous comment is designed to show that this really is a simple argument, so induction is a bit over the top. An alternate method of proof would be using linearity of expectation: if we let $X$ denote the number of offspring of a given individual, so that $Z_m$ is made up of individuals $X_1,\ldots, X_{Z_m}$ then  $$ \mathbf E[Z_{m+1}|Z_m] = \sum_{k=1}^{Z_m} \mathbf E[X_k] = \sum_{k=1}^{Z_m} \mu = \mu Z_m$$

Comment: okay, got it, and when you went from $\mathbb{E}[Z_{m+1}| Z_{m}]$ to the second equation, you are able to do that because $\mathbb{E}[X_k| Z_m]=\mathbb{E}[X_k]$ since $X_k$ and $Z_m$ are independent?

Comment: Also, technically there sshould be $Z_{m+1}$ individuals so the summation should go from k=1 to $k=Z_{m+1}$ right?